# How to add multiple solution files to a single project from github (VS 2019)

Tags: visual-studio, github, visual-c++, solution

I'm new to Visual Studio. I am trying to learn how to ray trace using "Ray Tracing in a Weekend." I'd like to use VS 2019 to compile/debug, but I can't figure out how to create a solution for each sub-directory of the following code: https://github.com/RayTracing/raytracing.github.io

I've attempted to File>New>Project from existing code, but this dmps all the .cpp and .h files from each smaller project into headers and src files, ruining the point of having smaller projects. Is this bad design on the repo owner's part? Is it possible to have multiple solutions to run each one separately? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Following [How to: Create a C++ Project from Existing Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/how-to-create-a-cpp-project-from-existing-code?view=vs-2019), I would create three solutions, with three separate imports, one for each of the folders inside [`RayTracing/raytracing.github.io/src`](https://github.com/RayTracing/raytracing.github.io/tree/master/src)

Once csproj files ahve been generated for each projects in each solution, you can a plugin like [Add Multiple Projects To Solution](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MaciejGudanowicz.AddMultipleProjectsToSolution) to group them in one solution.